# Do you pronounce the T ending sound?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

As I was taught in school and , the T ending sound of words is unvoiced and should be pronounced with air, but recently I met a friend from the US, those aired T sounds were missing from her speaking, like "hat", "hot", "right". She speaks like /hæ/, /hɑː/,/raɪ/.

So I wonder if it's common to miss those sounds for Americans?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phonemic /t/ can have at least these allophones in English, depending on speaker and situation:

- [tʰ]
- [t]
- [t̞]
- [t̪]
- [ɾ]
- [ʔ]

The last one is what you are hearing in that speaker; it is the same glottal stop that occurs between the two identical vowels in *the eel*.

[Wikipedia notes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_chart_for_English_dialects#cite_note-2) that /t/ can become

> [ʔ] in some positions in Scottish English, English English, American English, and Australian English

Comment: The word *Scottish* is itself one example.

Comment: @Andrew: but only in some dialects. It'd usually be a flap in the U.S.

Comment: I searched "glottal stop" and I was shocked by the variations of how T can be pronounced. May I ask if the glottal stop would also apply to "d"?

Comment: I can't think of an accent where /d/ is realised as a glottal stop.

Comment: [ʔ]  The glottal stop described, and exampled in the word *Scottish*, is considered to be lazy speech in Scotland, but is used more often instead of whole parts of words.  It's an epidemic.